# Handle data from ajax request after call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-get

I'm using ajax to get the returned value from php function, the call is correct but I can't access the data properly.

The ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
            data:  {"hotel_id" : hotel_id},
            url:   '/get_type_check',
            type:  'get',     
            success:  function (response) {

                    console.log(response);
            },

             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
}    
    });
```

If I print the console log shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

comment:
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.

```
{"status":["CAB2"]}
```

And the php function:

```
 public function get_type_check(){


    $type_checks=Hotel::get_type_checks($_GET['hotel_id']);

    echo json_encode(array('status' => $type_checks));

}
```

How can I get the response.status?

Should I use return instead of "echo"?

Comment: Return it don't use echo

Comment: response.status still undefined

Comment: what is the data in console.log(response)?

Comment: Sorry maybe the question was wrong. Now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the response to json to catch it as json.

Just add the line:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(response);
```

So your ajax will as follows:

```
$.ajax({
                data: {"hotel_id": hotel_id},
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(response) {

                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);

                    console.log(data.status);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus);
                    alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: There is an error with the response or something "unexpected token <"

Comment: what you expecting from your php side? just post it as array please

Comment: I expect the result of the php function. For example {"status":["CAB2"]}

Comment: yes i understand you expecting the result fo the php function. but did you check your php function is giving you the result first. how do you know php function is giving you the result you expecting?

Comment: your ajax url is with [.php] ??? how can you fire the function with this url!!! you can't do that.

Comment: Sorry I replaced the real url but the result is what I want, if I echo the result is {"status":["CAB2"]}. But I don't know how can I access by the response.

Comment: Thanks guy, I got a stupid comment at the beginning of the web app. Sorry for lose your time.